# recursively find average of binary tree values pseudo code

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, average, pseudocode

I need to find the average of values of binary tree recursively.

Is this pseudo code ok?

```
avg (T)
if (|T| = 1)
    return value
sumleft = sumleft + avg(Tleft)
sumright = sumright + avg(Tright)
sum = value + sumleft + sumright
return sum / (|Tleft| + |Tright| +1)
```

Comment: if |T| = 0 there is no value

Answer (score 0):

No, the code is not correct. In the recursive calls, the callee returns[*] the *average* whereas the caller treats it as if it were the *sum*.

[*] Well, it would if it were correct, which it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

As NPE said, the code isn't correct because the function returns an average, which the caller treats as a sum. A simple fix to your pseudo code would be:

```
avg(T) =
  if (|T| = 1)
    return value
  sumleft  = |Tleft | * avg(Tleft )
  sumright = |Tright| * avg(Tright)
  sum = value + sumleft + sumright
  return sum / (|Tleft| + |Tright| + 1)
```

You will need to make sure that the result of avg is not an integer, because there may be many round off errors as a result of the division. Here's code that would be better and less prone to round-off errors:

```
sum(T) =
  if (|T| = 1)
    return value
  return sum(Tleft) + value + sum(Tright)
avg(T) =
  return sum(T) / |T|
```